# How to organize data in pivot using multiple condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a below-mentioned dataframe:

DF:

```
ID      Date                 Status     Remark       Flag        Value     reps_rt
P-1     20/03/2020  19:08:09 SA         1            L           10000     RI
P-1     20/03/2020  19:08:09 SA         1            L           10000     KT
P-1     20/03/2020  19:08:09 SA         1            L           10000     JS
P-2     20/03/2020  20:08:09 SA         2            K           15000
P-3     20/03/2020  21:08:09 SA         2            J           20000     PO
P-4     20/03/2020  20:08:09 SA         2            H           20000     MK
P-4     20/03/2020  20:08:09 SA         2            H           20000     SS
P-4     20/03/2020  20:08:09 SA         2            H           20000     SA
P-5     20/03/2020  17:08:09 RE                      G           8000
P-6     20/03/2020  12:08:09 RE         1                        6000      RF
P-7     20/03/2020  11:08:09 XA         1                        13000
P-8     19/03/2020  19:08:09 SA         1            L           15000     LO
P-9     19/03/2020  11:08:09 SA                      K           10000     JJ
P-10    19/03/2020  10:08:09 SA         2            J           10000     NO
```

I want to get the following output using the `DF`, where the `Status` column has distinct 3 values and `Remarks` has also distinct 3 values 1, 2 or [null], `Flag` column has distinct 6 values with [null]. For one distinct `ID` we have multiple entry of `reps_rt` column.

I Need to create the following dataframe, by creating a 3 group based on `Value` like 0-15000, 15000-50000.

- If for a distinct ID `Flag` has some value other than 0 or [null]/NA but `reps_rt` has value 0 or [null]/NA then it would be `a`.
- If for a distinct ID `resp_rt` has some value other than 0 or [null]/NA but `Flag` has value 0 or [null]/NA then it would be `b`
- If for a distinct ID both `Flag` & `resp_rt` has some value other than 0 or [Null]/NA then it would be `c`
- If for a distinct ID both `Flag` & `resp_rt` has value 0 or [Null]/NA the it would be `d`

`20/03/2020                 0 - 15000                         15000 - 50000
Status      count   percent  L K J H G [Null] count   percent  L K J H G [Null]   Total
SA            2      2/5     1 1 0 0 0   1      2              0 0 1 1 0    0       4
a             1      1/2     0 1 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
b             0       -      0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
c             1      1/2     1 0 0 0 0   0      2              0 0 1 1 0    0       3
d             0       -      0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
RE            2      2/5     0 0 0 0 1   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       2
a             1              0 0 0 0 1   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
b             1              0 0 0 0 0   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
c             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
d             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
XA            1              0 0 0 0 0   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
a             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
b             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
c             0              0 0 0 0 0   0      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       0
d             1              0 0 0 0 0   1      0              0 0 0 0 0    0       1
Total         5              1 1 0 0 1   3      2              0 0 1 1 0    0       7`

I have mentioned the required output based on the latest date which is 20/03/2020, if the dataframe don't have the latest date as per `startdate` keep all the value 0 in the output dataframe. The percentage column is just for the reference there will be calculated percentage values,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output format looks more like an Excel pivot table or a table for a report than an R dataframe for analysis. Especially with the sub-total rows and columns. However, R has many more tools for working with tidy rectangular data than it does for producing pivot or report tables with sub-total rows. So you may be better off choosing a different tool (like Excel) that more naturally produces the output structure you are seeking.

If you determined to do this in R, then a simple starting point would be `mutate`, `ifelse`, and `summarise` something like the following:

```r
df %>% mutate(L = ifelse(Flag == "L",1,0),
              K = ifelse(Flag == "K",1,0),
              # etc for Flag) %>%
  mutate(sub_status = NA) %>%
  mutate(sub_status = ifelse(!is.na(Flag) & reps_rt == 0, "a", sub_status),
         sub_status = ifelse(is.na(Flag) & reps_rt != 0, "b", sub_status),
         # etc for sub-status) %>%
  mutate(value_class = ifelse(0 <= Value & Value <= 15000, "0-15000", "15000-50000")) %>%
  group_by(Date, status, sub_status, value_class) %>%
  summarise(L = sum(L),
            K = sum(K),
            # etc
            count = n())
```

You would then have to filter to the date of interest, and reshuffle the values around to match your desired format.

Comment: It is unclear to me from your comment what the error is or where it is occurring.

Comment: Also note that the code I provided in my answer is only an example starting point. You will need to extend it, and also check things like correct spelling (and capitalization) of variable names.

Comment: Yes, I did that...still facing some issues.